# when I host web site in local IIS server signalr not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, signalr-hub

When i host web site to local iis server SignalR not working

when i get another api request like : 192.168.20.33:2323/api/City work for me

[image: View Image]

Answer (score 0):

It requires **WebSocket installation** in IIS. For installation of WebSocket:

1. Open Server Manager in IIS.
2. Under the Manage menu, click Add Roles and Features.
3. Select Role-based or Feature-based Installation, and then click Next.
4. Select the appropriate server, (your local server is selected by default), and then click Next.
5. Expand Web Server (IIS) in the Roles tree, then expand Web Server, and then expand Application Development.
6. Select WebSocket Protocol, and then click Next.
7. Click Install.

Hope this helps.